Oven Light-fixture
I turned on my electric fan oven and at the same time the light inside blew. The glass has come out of its own metal holder, so still inside the oven light socket. How the hell do I remove it? I also don’t have a new bulb to take its place. Do I have to have a new bulb in before I can use the oven again?

Turn off the power to the oven. Remove the lens. Take a pair of needle nose pliers and grab the bulb base with the jaws. Rotate the pliers towards the center of the base. Use the pliers to rotate the base out of the socket. Replace the lens. Turn the power back on. Use the oven until you get a new bulb.

@DelphicOracle Sounds like a correct answer to me.

Turn off the power to the oven. Remove the lens. Take a pair of needle nose pliers and grab the bulb base with the jaws. Rotate the pliers towards the center of the base. Use the pliers to rotate the base out of the socket. Replace the lens. Turn the power back on. Use the oven until you get a new bulb.

You can also use a potato (which you'll throw out afterwards due to glass contamination) or a specialized insulated plastic and rubber broken bulb removal tool (I have the latter due to a situation with a bulb I could not identify the circuit for and not wanting to turn off the whole house. It's one of those tools used rarely, but not too expensive and nice to have when needed.)

And if you can't get the thing to turn with the pliers (maybe it's gunked up or corroded in place), you might be able to bash the "guts" of the bulb out, and use the pliers to basically fold part of the metal threaded section so that it's smaller in the socket and will turn easier.
